# Override Hide of main form with button in second form

Tags: c#, button, hide, show

I have a stupid and i think dumb question.

i am building an windows application to go to an login page for an website but it has 2 forms 1 to go to the login and redirect to the stock exachange acount of the user that works fine but when the user clicks the stock exchage rate bunnton the main forn wil hide.

Now for the seccond form there i have a button that need to override that hide but it does'nt
code for the button on de Koers Form to go back to the Belegen form
have tried if else statements but they dont work.

```
  private void Belegen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Belegen.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

The button om the Belegen form to open stock reates Koers form

```
private void Koersen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            Koers Koers = new Koers();
            Koers.Show();
            this.Hide();

        }
```

Can some one help me out.

basicly what i want is when i click the Koers button Bellegen need to hide and when ik click Belegen in the Koers form Koers needs to hide and belegen needs to be unhidden but Koers need to be opend als well and both forms need to be usable not just one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understandy your description, but looking at the code, you should use instances of the forms, and not static calls on the classes themselves.

```
public class Test {

private Belegen belegen; // do not forget to initialize
private Koers koers; // do not forget to initialize

private void Belegen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    this.belegen.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }


private void Koersen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        koers.Show();
        this.Hide();

    }
}
```

You might have split those two two forms in your example. Then you just need to have a reference to Koersen in the Belegen form, and vice versa.